# Cannot find a way to delete an element previously loaded by jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, search

I am building a website to combine the search of two stores in my country.
The way I am doing it now is a weird hybrid between curl and jquery. First, I save the page with cURL
and then display it with jQuery. Now, I have the problem of removing some elements from the part of the
previously loaded page from jQuery.
Here is my code:

(Should probably mention that it is working with elements not loaded by JQuery)

```
 <?php
$ch = curl_init();                                                    //for now just saving a static result (/rouska) instead of using $_GET or post or something
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.sbazar.cz/hledej/rouska'); //save output of shop1
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
file_put_contents("cache.php", $data);
curl_close($ch);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.bazos.cz/search.php?hledat=rouska');  //save output of shop2
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
file_put_contents("cache2.php", $data);

curl_close($ch);


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
<table id="div">
<script>
$('div').load('cache.php .c-item-list'); //Loading a specific class from the store file, for now just one store for easy troubleshooting
$(".c-item-list").remove();  //Trying to remove everything that was previously loaded just for testing
</script>
</table>
</div>



<h2>WOW this is END</h2>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `load()` is async so you're calling `remove()` *before* the elements exist. You need to call `remove()` *after* instead, eg. from the click of your `button`

Comment: First, Structure and Format your code peoperly. There's no `</head>`

Comment: This is just testing, the code will be formatted MUCH better.

Comment: Rory McCrossan, I don't exactly understand what you mean. I need to filter out a class of elements BEFORE they get displayed. Specifically, it's a button that the shop includes inside it.

Comment: ¨Solved it: used this to delete it after the page finished loading: $(window).bind("load", function() {
   $(".c-item-list").remove();
});